# Github action terminate helm orphan process and release stuck in "pending-install"

Tags: kubernetes-helm, github-actions, azure-aks, orphan-process

I'm creating a GitHub action pipeline to deploy backend application to AKS. I try to follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/aks-deployment-pipeline-github-actions. First, I follow along with the tutorial with my demo project, which works perfectly fine. After that, I apply to exist backend project then something goes wrong.

1. When deploy on resources aren't upgrade.
2. Helm release status is shown as "pending-install", but my demo project is in "deployed" status.
3. Github action terminates the orphan process on complete job step, but there isn't an orphan process in the demo project.[Please see image of pipeline log for reference]

Demo pipeline
[image]

Backend project pipeline
[image]

What I've done.

- I've tried removing all Helm resource(including Helm secret) manually and redo again, but I still face the same error.
- I've tried to compare every configuration between demo project and backend project but I cannot catch any mismatch.
- If I helm install backend project from my laptop using the same command but manually inject variable, it works(The release is in deployed status).

Other useful information

- Helm version on pipeline: v3.3.1
- Helm command that I currently use:

```
- name: Run Helm Deploy
        run: |
          helm upgrade \
            --debug \
            --install \
            --create-namespace \
            --atomic \
            --wait \
            --timeout 30m0s \
            --namespace dev \
            xxxx-release-dev \
            ./helm --set image.repository=${{ secrets.ACR_NAME }} --set mongo.url=${{ secrets.MONGO_URL_DEV }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://www.facebook.com/groups/devopsthailand/ Admin to helps me find out the answer. Github action secrets.MONGO_URL_DEV contains the special character that is needed to put a double quote between. Those special characters weird behavior when executed. After putting a double quote in, it works!!.